# How can you determine the namespace and URN of a web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I need to write a SOAP request to a web service.
It is not working and I am narrowed it down to how I am defining the namespace in the .setRequestHeader "SoapAction" function or the actual SoapRequest string.

The request header requires the parameter [namespace]/[method] of the web service.

I have the web service code and in the .cs file the namespace is `PagingService`.
The wsdl for the service is:

```
http://<server>:<port>/PagingService/PagingService.Paging.svc?WSDL.
```

When I run a console application and access the vbscript, it returns the wsdl when I do a 'GET' and 'Send()' using the httpRequest object.  So, I think this is fine.
I have to set the namespace with the method name in the setRequestHeader function:

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", "PagingService/TestMethod"
```

Is this the correct way to set the namespace/method in the second parameter of this function?
If this is correct, my SoapRequest string must be wrong.
It requires the `urn` of the web service.  How do I determine that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine the SOAPAction of a web service method:
1. Open the WSDL
2. Find the method that you want to call
3. In my WSDL, the soap action was an attribute of the method.
It looked like this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="TestMethod">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPaging/TestMethod" style="document"/>
```

The namespace is `http://tempuri.org/IPaging`
The method is: `TestMethod`